# Where do I find information about what is wrong with my eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I just 'installed', i.e. unzipped eclipse 3.5.2 and tried to start it. I just shows the wait cursor for a short amount of time and thats it. How can I find out, what is wrong?

Are there any log files a can check? I searched the directories but couldn't find anything useful.

Eclipse Version 3.5.2 (I use it, because I want to run the scala IDE)

Windows 7 (64bit)

JDK: 1.6.0_22 (specified in eclipse.ini) (64bit)

Note: Eclipse 3.6. works just fine

Update:
Looks like eclipse didn't even get so far to create a log file ... any other tipps what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get more info about what is going on, you should launch eclipse in a command line invoking the jvm, instead of using the exe, this way you could probably see some error logging to the console...

As explained [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F) run:

```
java -jar eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.0.v20070606.jar
```

You might need to change the version number of the jar to suit 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse's log files are located at:

1. `<workspace>/.metadata/.log`
2. `<eclipse install>/configuration/<sometimestamp>.log`
3. `<eclipse install>/configuration/org.eclipse.update/install.log`

Comment: Hmm ... since it doesn't start at all, there is no workspace. The other two places are empty as well.